# A question about PSChildPaneSpecifier [iPhone SDK]

Tags: iphone

i am using PSChildPaneSpecifier on Setting bundle to show  Acknowledgements about my application on setting bundle ,so how can handle my plist file to show many texts ? like iwork apps Acknowledgements
thank you

i mean something like this :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a lot of [PSGroupSpecifier](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/preferencesettings/conceptual/settingsapplicationschemareference/Articles/PSGroupSpecifier.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007009-SW1) in that acknowledgement file. Each PSGroupSpecifier should contain a paragraph of text.

Comment: i guessed but i don't know why doesn't work ! it means doesn't show anything ! i create plist file and add PSGroupSpecifier as type and some string as Title ! but nothing happens , why ?

Comment: @Momeks: Make sure the PSChildPaneSpecifier is linked to the correct file name?

Comment: iam sure , see this pic :

http://www.i-phone.ir/forums/uploadedpictures/b78994d8d2b60aab8b24551e927d554c.png

Comment: @Momeks: Put the Title, StringsTable etc right below "Root", not below "New item".

Comment: dosen't work ! i tried many ways ! but i don't know why ! :

http://www.i-phone.ir/forums/uploadedpictures/27ab2b59c2e91d6aef8167f9a4dd4ed8.png

Comment: @Momeks: What is your Root.plist?